# Reading an array of data from XML

Tags: c++, xml, game-development, tinyxml

I'm unloading an array of data from с++ object to a XML file.
How can I get data from their attribute (in my case the attribute name is "Data"),
and save result to some buffer for further data manipulation?

I'm using the TinyXml library.

Function saving an object (see the result in XML below)

```
TiXmlDocument doc("text.xml");
if (!doc.LoadFile())
    return false;

TiXmlHandle hDoc(&doc);
TiXmlElement* elem;
TiXmlHandle hRoot(0);

elem = hDoc.FirstChildElement().Element();
if (!elem) return false;
std::string  name = elem->Value();
hRoot = TiXmlHandle(elem);

TiXmlElement* chunkbranch = new TiXmlElement("ChunkBranch");
root->LinkEndChild(chunkbranch);

for (int x = 0; x < this->mapChunk.size(); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < this->mapChunk[x].size(); y++)
    {
        TiXmlElement* chunk;
        chunk = new TiXmlElement("Chunk");
        chunkbranch->LinkEndChild(chunk);
        chunk->SetAttribute("posX", x);
        chunk->SetAttribute("posY", y);

            TiXmlElement* chunkdata;
        chunkdata = new TiXmlElement("ChunkData");
        chunk->LinkEndChild(chunkdata);
        chunkdata->SetAttribute("data", this->mapChunk[x][y]->getChunkAsString().c_str());
        //maybe can be use some other method for saving data?
    }
}
```

Here I'm calling attribute "ChunkData".
Here trying to get array values "ChunkBranch" >> "ChunkData" >> data

```
elem = hRoot.FirstChild("ChunkBranch").FirstChild().Element();

for (elem; elem; elem = elem->NextSiblingElement())
{
    std::string buff("");
    buff = elem->Value();

    if (buff == "Chunk")
    {
        int buffX;
        int xKey = elem->QueryIntAttribute("posX", &buffX);
        int yKey = elem->QueryIntAttribute("posY", &buffX);
        this->mapChunk[xKey][yKey] = &Chunk(sf::Vector2f(xKey,yKey));
        std::cout << "In chunk:\t" << xKey << " x " << yKey<< "\n";

        TiXmlElement* cData;
        cData = elem->FirstChildElement("ChunkData");

        int test;
        const char* pKey = cData->Value();
        const char* xke = cData->GetText();
        cData->QueryIntAttribute("data", &test);//<< somewhere here the  
        //program doesn't return array
        //and pKey = 0 (not NULL, just 0), after loading it will stop
```

XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<base>
    <ChunkBranch>
        <Chunk posX="0" posY="0">
            <ChunkData data="0 19 0 0 0 0 0 19 0 0 0 0 0 0 19 19 0 0 0 0 0 " />
        </Chunk>
        <Chunk posX="0" posY="1">
            <ChunkData data="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 19 0 0 0 0 0 19 0 0 0 0 0 0 19 19 0 0 0 0 0 "/>
    </ChunkBranch>
</base>
```

Comment: Is your question how you save the XML data or how you load it?

Comment: how load data from XMl file to some buffer, for further work with data

Comment: is there always just one ChunkBranch that contains many Chunks and each Chunk contains one ChunkData? Or can there be more than one ChunkBranch?

Comment: yes there is one ChunkBranch in which, there can be more "Chunk" with one "ChunkData"
i want to extract data from attribute "Data", into a temporary buffer, but dont know how didit

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using TinyXML-1 rather than TinyXML-2?

Comment: I was looking for any library for working with XML files, and I remembered tinyxml, but I hear about titixml2 for the first time